# What is a skillful way to meditate in the midst of a migraine headache?

Tags: personal-practice, lay-buddhism, suffering

> When the Bod-hisattva Quan the Am, who has been such a source of
>   inspiration of peace workers in Viet- nam, saw into the reality of the
>   five aggregates giving rise to emptiness of self, she was liberated
>   from every suffering, pain, doubt, and anger. -- The Miracle of Mindfulness, p. 48

I have been practicing mindfulness for less than a year. I have had some deep experiences and found benefit. However, when I have a migraine headache my mindfulness feels completely useless.

Any guidance or any good resources that would teach me to practice my mindfulness in the midst of a bad headache would appreciated.

Comment: As a fellow migraine sufferer who feels one coming no right now, I would also be very happy to hear good answers :) Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this](https://innerself.com/Meditation/brahm_11144.htm) story by Ajahn Brahm about dealing with intense bodily pain (toothache).

Read the following exercise only after you read that story.(otherwise you will mis-understand)

**Exercise**

When you have a migrane attack, take a deep breath really deep, fill your lungs completely. Now, hold this as long as you can. Initially this time is 4-5 seconds but it becomes 10 seconds which is enough.

What happens is your body goes in shock and some 'fight or flight' harmones are released. This focused attention gives extream boost for mindfulness of migrane itself.

**In this situation become mindful of your migrane and do what Ajahn Brahm has told to do.**

When you cannot hold the breath any longer, let go of all the breath, empty the lungs and repeat the exrecise. This is bit difficult than holding the breath, you can do the first step.

Preferably keep your eyes closed.

Pain goes away.

***Don't do this while driving or doing anything else. Just make sure you are just sitting doing nothing while doing this.***

Comment: Thank you! I will read the story and try the techniques suggested.

Answer (score 3):

**Theravada Buddhist Answer based in the Burmese method as taught by the Ven. Mahasi Sayadaw**.

The following method is based in Vipassana meditation. This type of meditation is characterized by taking reality as an object of meditation, meaning that one directs attention towards the most apparent object in the present moment.

In terms of a migraine attack one might focus on the pain, nausea if present, a feeling of lightheadedness or ones reaction towards those objects.

One would note whatever object is most predominant and change object when another object becomes predominant. One *notes* the pain by mentally and slowly saying to oneself *"pain, pain, pain"*. This is done while keeping attention on the object. One notes in order to create clear comprehension about the object, so to not fall into either liking or disliking of the object.

When this is done repeatedly over a period of time the mind will come to see the pain as merely an object. One will come to understand that the pain is not a problem. Instead its our own reaction to the pain that creates suffering for us.

For more in-depth information on the method in relation to dealing with pain, I recommend the following video teachings given by Ven. Yuttadhammo:

- [*Ask A Monk: Dealing With Pain and Using Suffering as a Vehicle for Enlightenment*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BldDclolLCg)
- [*Ask A Monk: Pain*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PD4fY65BXW0)
- [*Monk Radio: When Pain Becomes Unbearable*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWT69EvM1cQ)

He also made a booklet, which is available [*here*](https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/).

May you have a fruitful practice.

Comment: This is very interesting, but it almost sounds like concentration meditation instead of vipassana. To try to focus on the object ... being pain ... and establish one pointed concentration on that. You know, I never considered doing this, but it sounds fascinating. Like, I wonder if my monkey mind could finally concentrate single pointedly if I used *pain* as the object! I could also potentially use my aching knees as one of them is constantly in pain when sitting in half lotus.

Comment: They are in fact complete opposites. In Samatha (concentration) meditation on focuses on a single object to the exclusion of everything else. In Vipassana meditation one changes object depending on whatever object is most predominant. Vipassana meditation is designed to allow the meditator to gain insight into how reality functions, ie. how conditioned reality is *impermanent, unsatisfactory and uncontrollable (devoid of any self-essence)*.

Comment: I see. Same with the pain in headache I guess. This object is also arising, changing, and decaying constantly. But Samatha is often done with the breath as the object which also has that character...?

Comment: That is correct. The difference in Samatha meditation is that the object is a concept, in a way its artificial, since one tries to make it stable and permanent (which it isn't). In Vipassana meditation one takes reality as an object. One experiences how reality is ever-changing and not under our control. They are two different types of meditation designed for different purposes.

Comment: Thanks @Lanka, I think this is excellent and I have not seen the difference between serenity and insight meditation defined in this way. In my school, it is taught that one must *unite* serenity and insight meditation to perceive reality as it actually is. Does your school say the same? Using your definitions it I imagine it sounds something like, "To see in an (artificially) permanent and stable way the utterly impermanent and unstable nature of all things."

Comment: Yes, there are 3 approaches and all are equally valid. I can't find the sutta (Theravada Buddhism) now but I will insert it when I locate it. In the sutta the Buddha teaches that there are 3 vehicles to Enlightenment. One can practice Samatha first then Vipassana or Vice versa or Samatha and Vipassana togther, ie. in tandem. The former sounds like the approach in your tradition.

Comment: Wow, @Lanka! I had never heard of Vipassana meditation! Can't wait to do more research and study on it.

Comment: @Stanley. I'm happy that you found it useful. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Hey @Lanka, I have been using this technique over the last 2 days for some other things as well: hey fever, sinus pressure, post nasal drip, etc. I find that it is very useful unless I am trying to go to sleep. I am then faced with a choice: stay mindful of the current reality or take medicine so I can sleep. Any guidance on how to fall asleep while using Vipassana meditation to remain mindful? I can't turn my mind off enough to go to sleep when I am meditating like this. Thanks!

Comment: @Stanley. That sounds very good. This technique is pretty powerful and even after a short time of practicing one feels the benefits. Be aware that you are far from the only one that experiences challenges when going to sleep. Especially when practicing intensely for a while, ones sleep becomes very light and meditative in nature. I have heard Ajahn Punnadhammo explain that one should try to keep a more general mindfulness when going to sleep. So applying a broader, general and not laser-like mindfulness when going to sleep can be more fruitful. That's my own experience too...

Comment: ... You could try that and see if it works out. Remember that the body will fall alsleep if it needs it. The thing is that when we practice mindfulness of the present moment, i.e. the current object of reality (fever, sinus pressure etc.) we are not reacting. We are only experiencing, observing. So we are not weighed down by all the bagage (judging, liking, disliking) we usually associate with these objects. That means we do not spent energy on e.g. getting angry and then reacting to that anger and then feeding of it, until it baloons out of control...

Comment: ... We all know the snowballing effect these phenomena can lead to. When simply observing without reacting, we let go, we don't cultivate further addiction (clinging, aversion) to the object. Instead we just see the object for what it is and let it go.This way a healing and a cultivation and preservation of mental energy takes place, which in turn will result in less need for sleep. After having practiced for a while the mind will begin to understand and realize how burdenless and peaceful it is to dwell and establish itself in the present moment. It becomes inclined to stay there.

Comment: Ven. Yuttadhammo made some videos on sleep too. These are: [*Monk Radio: Need For Sleep*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38YcGlWPPOY), [*Ask A Monk: Meditation Before Sleeping*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIOm8T4eXRM), [*Sleeping Well*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URMo-w2PXGw), [*Ask A Monk: Falling Asleep While Meditating*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jhrqD9kPPY), [*Ask A Monk: Sleeping and Bedding for Meditators*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iilmCRyRjtU).